# Setting up handling unicode in Mediawiki Math extension

Tags: latex, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I am having trouble with some unicode characters inside `<math></math>` tags in Mediawiki.

For example, the following:

```
<math>′</math>
```

Results in: `Failed to parse (syntax error): {\displaystyle ′}` error.

I am using clean installation from [this docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mediawiki/) (version: 1.35.2).

I also downloaded, extracted and enabled most recent `Math` extension (by adding `wfLoadExtension( 'Math' );` to `LocalSettings.php`)

How can I make Mediawiki\Math handle unicode properly?

Comment: This happens on Wikipedia too, so it's not an issue with your installation.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Indeed. However, it works fine on, for example, "https://meta.miraheze.org", so, It is doable.